# In App Notifications For Social App IOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, xcode6

Does anybody know a way to implement in app notifications? 
For example like Facebook and Twitter have notifications in the app so if you receive a message or have been tagged you get a notification inside the app. Then when you click that notification it shows you a list of all the notifications you have received. 
I hope the question makes sense. 
Would appreciate any help. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook & Twitter uses Push Notification to notify the users. You need to implement push notification for it.

If you have feature which is local to the app then you can implement Local Notification.

Reference [link for both](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)

Comment: So If I tag you in a post on Facebook, and then you get the notification inside of Facebook with the little globe looking Icon, is that a push notification? Even though its not coming from facebook, but its coming from another user?

Comment: Yes its push notification. What happen let say you have tagged me at that time from the Facebook on notification will be generated & send it to me, So I will come know you tagged me.. Same thing happen when user comment on anything or like anything..

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. Do you know of any tutorials on how I can make this work inside of my app? I know how to setup push notifications with Parse, where I can send out a push notification to all the users, but I need to figure out how the push notification will be sent from 1 user to another. I am adding a friend request button in the app and that's what I need it for. So a user is notified that someone has sent a request. Thanks

Comment: Push notification works on device token bases.. So you need to store the device token of other user on server. Then you need to use that token to send the notification to that user. Once you set up the push notification in your application delegate method "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" get called. From that method you can retrieve token for that user & then you can store that in your server for further utilisation.

Comment: @NileshPatel link is down.

Answer (score 0):

I am using pushapps site for notifications. Easy to implement,  easy to use. http://www.pushapps.mobi/